# How can I capture and store data from a repeating HL7 segement?

Tags: hl7, mirth

We currently capture data from `HL7` messages like below and then insert the same in database. This is easy as it is value from a single segment

```
var vACC_NO =checkSize("ACC",msg['PID']['PID.3']['PID.3.1'].toString(),20);
INSERT INTO adt_tab ( SITEID,ACC_NO) VALUES (vSITEID,vACC_NO);
```

Now I need to capture `DG1` segment data, where we have multiple `DG1` segments in `HL7` message. And also need to store in Database

```
| DG1        |            1 | ICD10 | I22.8^MYOCARDIAL INFARCT^ICD10 | MYOCARDIAL |               |   |  |  |  |  |   |  |  |  |   |
| INFARCTION | 201702010437 | B     |                                |            |               |   |  |  |  |  | 7 |  |  |  |   |
| DG1        |            2 | ICD10 | A44.9^ORGANISM^ICD10           | ORGANISM   | 20170201 0437 | B |  |  |  |  |   |  |  |  | 7 |
```

So in my database table I have now more columns - `SITEID`, `ACC_NO`, `CODE1`, `CODE2`...
From the above message I need to insert `I22.8` into `CODE 1`, `A44.9` into `CODE2` and so on ..

How I should first capture these codes in loop from multiple `DG1` segments in the message ?
And then how I should store it in the database ?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything like powershell or plsql or something? Where is the code ?

Comment: I have to do in mirth using javascript

Comment: So where is the piece of code ?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to this. Our interface incharge person left and as a urgent requirement we have to process DG1 segments from HL7 messages. Until now we only process non repeating segments. Like below

Comment: Until now we process non repeating segments like EVN below. 
EVN|A01-|194897979
var vID =checkSize("ID",msg['EVN']['EVN.3']['EVN.3.1'].toString(),20);
INSERT INTO adt_tab ( SITEID,ACC_NO) VALUES (vID,vACC_NO);
Now we need to process DG1 segments and store in DB 
DG1|1|ICD10|I22.8
DG1|2|ICD10|A44.9
So I22.8 needs to be inserted in Code 1 column in DB table , A44.9 needs to be inserted in Code 2 column in DB table
Found this attached code but we don't use ChannelMap, instead a insert into DB

Comment: ***Code I found on the internet ****
Code to iterate over field

var Accession = new Array()
i = 0
for each (fld in msg['ORC']['ORC.2'])
{
Accession[i] = fld['ORC.2.1'].toString();
i=i+1;
}
var NumInArray=Accession.length;
var AccArray=Accession.toString();
channelMap.put('NumInArray',NumInArray);
channelMap.put('AccArray',AccArray);

fld is the variable that holds the preceding message string (['ORC']['ORC.2'][0])

this will work for any field that is repeated simply substitute msg['ORC']['ORC.2'] with the repeating field you want to iterate through

Comment: Need to take diag codes from each DG1 segment and store them in a single row in the database  ( as columns)

Comment: Please edit the question and put them in the question itself to help you out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the segments like this

```
for each (dg1 in msg['DG1']){
    variable1 = dg1['DG1.3']['DG1.3.1'];
    variable2 = dg1['DG1.3']['DG1.3.2'];

    // database call with the previus
    databaseCall(variable1,variable2, ...    
}
```

For each segment you are going to do an insert.

Apart from this, I do not think is a good idea to make more columns in the same row by adding variable1, variable2, variable3 ... as it is not normalized and it not a good database design practice.